# Delete Row DataSource Issue - Invalid Update: Invalid number of rows in section 0 with Xamarin.iOS

Tags: json, uitableview, xamarin.ios

Experts,

I have a UITableView that populates with some cells from a JSON file.  I want the users to swipe to delete a specific cell.  I implemented the delete functionality using SWTableViewCell component, and almost got it working with an issue:  "Invalid Update:  Invalid number of rows in section 0".  I'm suspecting I need to remove the object from the datasource and my JSON file in my model, but not sure how to go about it.  Thanks in advance!

Here is the implementation:

```
public override void DidTriggerLeftUtilityButton(SWTableViewCell cell, nint index)
        {
            // Delete button was pressed

            switch (index)
            {
                case 0:

                    NSIndexPath cellIndexPath = tableView1.IndexPathForCell(cell);
                    dataList.RemoveAt(cellIndexPath.Row);
                    tableView1.DeleteRows(new[] { cellIndexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Left);

                    break;
            }
        }

public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return dataList.Count;
        }
```

Here is the model that populates the JSON:

```
public class DataLocalNotifications
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string NotificationMessage { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string logo { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set;}
    public double longitude { get; set;}
    public string website { get; set; }
    public double phone { get; set; }
    public string yelp { get; set; }

    public DataLocalNotifications()
    {
    }

}

    public class LocalNotificationsModel
{
    List<DataLocalNotifications> _model = new List<DataLocalNotifications>();
    public List<LocalNotificationsModel> businessList = new List<LocalNotificationsModel>();
    public static LocationManager Manager { get; set; }
    public double distance;
    CLLocationManager location;
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Long { get; set; }

    public DataLocalNotifications this[int index]
    {
        get { return _model[index]; }
        set { _model[index] = value; }
    }

    public List<DataLocalNotifications> data
    {

        get { return _model; }
        set { _model = value; }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _model.Count; }
    }

    public void Add(DataLocalNotifications item)
    {
        _model.Add(item);

    }

    public static LocalNotificationsModel Init()

    {
        LocalNotificationsModel model = new LocalNotificationsModel();
        string documentsPath1 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        var localPath1 = Path.Combine(documentsPath1, "Notifications.json");
        var project1= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectNotifications> (System.IO.File.ReadAllText (localPath1));
        //project1.Notifications.Reverse();
        foreach (var bus in project1.Notifications.OrderByDescending(x => x.UnixTime))
        {

            model.Add(new DataLocalNotifications
            {
                NotificationMessage = bus.BusinessNotification,
                name = bus.Name_Location,
                date = bus.Date,
                logo = bus.BusinessImage,
                latitude = bus.Latitude,
                longitude = bus.Longitude,
                website = bus.Website,
                phone = bus.Phone,
                yelp = bus.Yelp
            });

        }
        return model;

    }
```

Comment: Why not to use standar swipe to delete ?

Comment: Standard swipe to delete, I would get the same result.  Plenty of advantages for me to use the component.

Comment: Hmm.. I can show how it can be implemented via native stuff(without component). If you want,i will provide sample.

Comment: That would be greatly appreciated! @XTL

Comment: @pkozowlski check answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets try an simple example.

Make **ViewController** and drop there **TableView** (also, you can add **NavigationController** for beautiful **NavBar** at top). Put orange Give "**CELL_ID**" for **reuse-identifier** on Cell parameter and make new class for e.g. **MyCell**.
Your storyboard should looks like(i have changed background of Cell and Label, so it's doesn't matter) :
[image]

And thats how will look your custom **Cell** class :

```
public partial class MyCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        public MyCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public void Update(string Data)
        {
            TxtLbl.Text = Data;
        }
    }
```

**TxtLbl** - is an name for our label that is located inside of **Cell**

Make additional custom **TableSource** class, like this one:

```
public class MySource : UITableViewSource
    {
        List<string> SourceData;

        public MySource(List<string> _SourceData)
        {
            SourceData = _SourceData;
        }


        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var Cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("CELL_ID") as MyCell;

            Cell.Update(SourceData[indexPath.Row]);

            return Cell;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return SourceData.Count;
        }

        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);

        }

        public override void CommitEditingStyle(UITableView tableView, UITableViewCellEditingStyle editingStyle, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            switch (editingStyle)
            {
                case UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete:
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Source List until remove equals to {SourceData.Count} count");
                    SourceData.RemoveAt(indexPath.Row);
                    tableView.DeleteRows(new NSIndexPath[] { indexPath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Remove {indexPath.Row} index");
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Source List after removing elements equals to {SourceData.Count}count");
                    break;
                case UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None:
                    Console.WriteLine("CommitEditingStyle:None called");
                    break;
            }
        }
        public override bool CanEditRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return true; // return false if you wish to disable editing for a specific indexPath or for all rows
        }

        public override string TitleForDeleteConfirmation(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {   // Optional - default text is 'Delete'
            return "Delete it!";
        }
    }
```

And the most interesting part for you is three methods : **CanEditRow** , **TitleForDeleteConfirmation** ,  **CommitEditingStyle** .

inside your **ViewController** on method **ViewDidLoad()** where is stored **TableView** :

```
var List = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                List.Add($"My Item #{i.ToString()}");
            }
            MyTable.Source = new MySource(List);
```

And the result is :
[image: resultl]